# Nodejs how to use map of object?

Tags: json, node.js, dictionary, hashmap

Hi i have a json like this called body:

```
{
  data: {
    id:1,
    name:hallo
  },
  paging: {
    cursors: {
      next: "abc"
    }
  }
}
```

so I have to save it into a map and then I'll need to print or to modify it.
If I save it with this code

```
var Map = require("collections/map");

var new_body = JSON.parse(body)
var map = new Map(new_body);
```

I have some difficulties to print for example map.paging.cursor.next, how can I do it? maybe I had to define a structure of that map before inserting the json inside it, I don't know...

Comment: you mean `map.paging.cursors` ? ( with an s) . also this is not valid JSON, keys must be strings, and strings must be wrapped with double quotes. use http://jsonlint.com/ to check if a JSON is valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your json have errors. Correct them like this.

```
{
  "data": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "hallo"
  },
  "paging": {
    "cursors": {
      "next": "abc"
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can parse the json like this and get the `paging.cursors.next` value.

```
var map = JSON.parse(body);//This will parse the json string
```

Now `map.paging.cursors.next` will have the value **"abc"**

Comment: i have done it but now it gives me this error: Debug: internal, implementation, error
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'cursors' of undefined.
It' s the same that it gave me before the changes, it read only paging like key and then cursors.next like and object....

Comment: I tested it before posting here and it worked. Can you post you code so that I can check it?

Comment: thanks you now it works i have written: console.log(map.get(paging)) but the correct code is console.log(map.get("paging")).